# JavaScript How to take all strings from an array and print them using filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter

If you don't understand the question, please see the code, i hope you will understand.
I want to take all strings that are in array, where in the same array have  numbers for example and Booleans

I have an array in JavaScript

```
var names = ['a','v','c','Earth',2,3,4,12,3,3434,true,false,'Fire'];
```

How to check how many strings are in the array and print then using filter?
I am trying to learn how to  use filter.

Comment: Did you try googling javascript array filter?

Answer (score 1):

Just use typeof operator:

```
var names = ['a','v','c','Earth',2,3,4,12,3,3434,true,false,'Fire'];

var onlyStringValues = names.filter(function (value) {
  return typeof value === 'string';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With filter in ES6 :

```
var names = ['a','v','c','Earth',2,3,4,12,3,3434,true,false,'Fire'];
var strings = names.filter(value => typeof value === 'string');
console.log(strings); // [ 'a', 'v', 'c', 'Earth', 'Fire' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
function stringFilter(arr) {

    var filtered = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

        if(typeof(arr[i]) === 'string') {

            filtered.push(arr[i]);
        }

    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `typeof` condition to select all strings, these can then be added to a new array, of which you can get the length and also print them out if you like.
For more information go here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer since you didn't provide any solution code. It should be a comment.

Comment: I can't comment directly yet, due to rep restrictions, I would have if I could.